# Does Node.js handle client requests one by one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

Does Node.js handle the client requests one by one? I have a project, which is using Node.js as a server-side proxy. According to my understanding, if you use a callback for a response, Node.js should respond to the new request without any delay, but actually the Node.js won't respond to the new request until it has finished the last callback. Is this the correct action or is there some incorrect code usage? Please help me on this. Thank you very much. Below is the code for re-sending requests to the back-end service.

```js
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');

function apiService(){}

apiService.prototype.get = function (context, payload, callback, url){
    return this.requestAPI(context, payload, callback, url, "GET");
}
apiService.prototype.post = function(context, payload, callback, url){
    return this.requestAPI(context, payload, callback, url, "POST");
}
apiService.prototype.del = function(context, payload, callback, url){
    return this.requestAPI(context, payload, callback, url, "DELETE");
}
apiService.prototype.requestAPI = function(context, payload, callback, url, method){

    var config = context.config;
    var targetUrl = config.APIHost
                    + (config.port == null ? "": (":" + config.port)) 
                    + "/" 
                    + config.baseDir
                    + "/"
                    + url;

    var requestObj = {
            url : targetUrl,
            json : true,
            pool: new http.Agent()
        }

    if (config.proxy != null){
        requestObj.proxy = config.proxy;
    }

    switch (method){
        case "POST":
            requestObj.body = payload;
            request.post(requestObj, function (err, resp, body){
                if (err){
                    callback(err);
                    return;
                }
                callback(null, body);
            });
            break;
        case "GET":
            var queryString = "";
            for (att in payload){
                if (queryString != "")
                    queryString += "&";
                queryString += att.toString() + "=" + payload[att];
            }
            if (queryString!="")
                requestObj.url += "?" + queryString;

            request.get(requestObj, function (err, resp, body){
                if (err){
                    callback(err);
                    return;
                }
                callback(null, body);
            });
            break;
        case "DELETE":
            requestObj.body = payload;
            request.del(requestObj, function (err, resp, body){
                if (err){
                    callback(err);
                    return;
                }
                callback(null, body);
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

```js
Current process

client       request1  ->       Node
client       request2  ->       Node
                                Node    server request1    ->backend
                                Node (waiting for event loop)
                                Node     <- server response1 backend
client       <- response1       Node
                                Node    server request2    ->backend
                                Node     <-  server response2 backend
client       <- response2       Node 
What I think it should be

  client       request1  ->       Node
client       request2  ->       Node
                                Node    server request1 ->     backend
                                Node (won't waiting for event loop)
                                Node    server request2 ->     backend
                                Node    <- server response2    backend
client       <-response2        Node
                                Node    <- server response1    backend 
client       <-response1        Node
```

**Updated:**

```js
               var params = {
      action : 'list'
    };
    $http.post('../../service/buildingBlockService', params)
    .success(function(buildingBlocks){
      callback(null, buildingBlocks);
     }).error(function(error){
      callback(error);
     })
```

The client requests are from Angular `$http`. On one page, there are several requests at the same time. According to my Fiddler monitor, the requests from the browser are sent without waiting, but the server re-send is one by one.

```js
app.post('/service/buildingBlockService', function (ctx, payload, req, res) {  
  var service1 = require('./service/buildingBlockService');
  var service = new service1();
  service.service(ctx, payload, function(error, result){
   res.send(200, result);
  });
 });
```

**Updated:** The middle layer of server request.

```js
var service = require('./apiService');

function BuildingBlockService(){
}

BuildingBlockService.prototype.init = function(){}

BuildingBlockService.prototype.service = function(context, payload, callback) { 
 var apiService = new service() 
 var params = payload;
 switch (params.action){
  case "list":
  default:
   apiService.get(context, null, callback, "BuildingBlocks");
   break;
 }
  
};  
  
module.exports = BuildingBlockService;
```

Comment: If you launch multiple requests to the same server in parallel, how the responses come back will be determined by the server that you sent the request to.  Some servers will work on multiple requests in parallel (in threads, for example) and other servers will work on one request at a time.  That depends upon the server design and the particular type of request.  Your node.js server will process the responses in the order they are received so whichever response gets back to your server first is the first one to start being processed.

Comment: You've shown some relevant code, but you've not shown the code that actually calls the shown code to produce the log you are asking about.  Please show the calling code.

Comment: Thank you very much for you quick response. I have updated the client side request code. I think the Node.js is using non-block I/O, is that including the Web Request? Or the non-blocking I/O just means for the whole process of one client request? I have used the Eclipse to debug Node.js. Yes, the server side request won't block the other codes, but it blocked the new client request. Is there some Node.js configuration need to be changed to support the function?

Comment: It seems you're asking about the behavior of the code that handles incoming proxy requests to your node.js server when you get multiple client requests in flight at the same time.  You aren't showing that proxy code so I can't really comment on that code without seeing it.  You also aren't showing the client code that actually launches multiple requests in flight at the same time.  The client code you have included seems to launch just one client request.

Comment: Thank you very much. The client side requests are initialed by angular client controls when they are loading. I think the client codes have no problems, because from the Fiddler Monitor all the requests are sent to the Node.js server. Yes, what I am asking is the behavior for Node.js to handle multiple requests at the same time. Does it process one after finished last request or it push the callback into event loop and process to the next, and when the proxy work finished, it trigger the callback in the event loop, then send back the response.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Does Node.js handle client requests one by one?

Yes and No.  node.js runs your JS single threaded.  That means that only one JS thread of execution is running at any given time.  So, if you had two requests like this:

```
// don't use this in real code, it's to simulate a point
function spin(t) {
    var start = Date.now();
    while (Date.now() < start + t) {}
}

app.post("/route1", req, res) {
    console.log("starting processing of /route1 request");
    // simulate taking several seconds of pure CPU to make a response
    spin(2000);
    res.send("done 1");
    console.log("finished processing of /route1 request");
}

app.post("/route2", req, res) {
    console.log("starting processing of /route2 request");
    // simulate taking several seconds of pure CPU to make a response
    spin(2000);
    res.send("done 2");
    console.log("finished processing of /route2 request");
}
```

And a /route1 request was immediately followed by a /route2 request, then the node.js server would process the /route1 request and not be able to do anything else until it was done with that request because the CPU was kept busy the entire time.

So, this would produce a log like this:

```
starting processing of /route1 request
finished processing of /route1 request
starting processing of /route2 request
finished processing of /route2 request
```

---

But, it is relatively rare that requests take a long time purely for CPU reasons.  Often requests involve some sort of I/O (files to read, database queries, other servers to contact, etc...).  If that I/O is done in an async fashion using async IO and not using synchronous IO, then multiple requests can easily be in flight at the same time and will be in flight at the same time because while the node.js server is waiting for I/O requests to complete, it is free to serve other requests and will serve other requests.

So, if you had this server code:

```
app.post("/route1", req, res) {
    console.log("starting processing of /route1 request");
    // simulate taking several seconds of pure CPU to make a response
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.send("done 1");
            console.log("finished processing of /route1 request");
        }
    });
}

app.post("/route2", req, res) {
    console.log("starting processing of /route2 request");
    // simulate taking several seconds of pure CPU to make a response
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.send("done 2");
            console.log("finished processing of /route2 request");
        }
    });
}
```

And a /route1 request was immediately followed by a /route2 request, then you would likely see this log (the order that the /route1 and /route2 responses finishes is not guaranteed - they could be in any order), but both responses will be processed in parallel:

```
starting processing of /route1 request
starting processing of /route2 request
finished processing of /route1 request
finished processing of /route2 request
```

---

If your node.js proxy server appears to be exhibiting serial processing behavior rather than parallel processing behavior, then that it could be that there is some sort of implementation issue in how you are implementing the proxy as it is certainly capable of having multiple requests in flight at the same time.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I think the node.js should be.  If possible, would you please help to review the codes, or give me some hints on what kind of codes may bring this issue. Sorry for late response.

Comment: By the way, I am using Fiddler and Eclipse to debug this issue. Should it be possible caused by the debug method? I mean the Node.js works as normal, but while debug or monitored by Fiddler, it acts like the wrong way.

Comment: @espider - I can't really say whether Fiddler or Eclipse might be influencing things.  You can always run your app without Fiddler or Eclipse with some `console.log()` debugging to track things.

Comment: Thank you very much. The host application is developed by another team. I have sent this topic to them. Thanks a lot for helping me confirmed the logic.

Comment: "(the order that the /route1 and /route2 responses finishes is not guaranteed" arent callbacks queued based on this https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ so response1 always finishes first since its the first that went into the callback queue. response2 waits its turn whether response1 takes longer time to process than response2

Comment: @johnnyq - The underlying callback is not queued for execution until the http response comes back from the other server and these two responses can come back in either order so the callbacks can be queued in either order.