# Can't set headers after they are sent at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express

I get error when push child row record (add Histories) from two clients which enter this add Histories page at the same time. It works fine if only push child record one by one client (i.e, enter add Histories pages to push record in client 1 and then enter add Histories pages to push record).

Is there some record lock handling required in AngularJS?

The error in the NodeJS service is:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/oracle/node/ang_backend1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:718:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/oracle/node/ang_backend1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:163:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/home/oracle/node/ang_backend1/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:249:15)
    at /home/oracle/node/ang_backend1/routes/datas.js:53:21
    at /home/oracle/node/ang_backend1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3324:16
    at /home/oracle/node/ang_backend1/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1924:15
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

It also cause the backend nodejs stop and needs restart.

The `HistoryaddController` is:

```
.controller('HistoryaddController', function($scope, $cordovaNetwork, $ionicPopup, $rootScope, $filter, $state, $stateParams, Movie, $ionicLoading, $ionicPlatform, $ionicHistory, $http, $timeout) {

    $scope.loadMovie = function() {

        $scope.movie = Movie.get({ id: $stateParams.id }).$promise.then(function(results) {
            console.log(results);
            $scope.movie = results;
        });
    };
    $scope.loadMovie();

    $scope.themovie = {
        details: '',
    };

    $scope.updateMovie = function() {

        $scope.movie.Histories.push($scope.themovie);
        $scope.movie.$update(function() {
            $state.go('movies');
        });
    };
})
```

The backend mongo model for this collection is:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
var connection = mongoose.createConnection("mongodb://localhost:27017/mymongodb");
autoIncrement.initialize(connection);
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var DataSchema = new Schema({
    sort: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Sort' },
    custname: String,
    problem: String,
    opendate: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    enddate: { type: Date },
    lastupdate: { type: Date },
    assignedon: { type: Date },
    openby: String,
    updateby: String,
    assignedto: String,
    severity: String,
    product: String,
    srstatus: String,
    reportby: String,
    custowner: String,
    vendorid: String,
    Histories: [{
        details: String
    }]
});

DataSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'Data');
module.exports = mongoose.model('Data', DataSchema);
```

The backend route is :

```
var Data = require('../app/models/data'); // get the mongoose model
var express = require('express');

var router = express.Router();

router.route('/:id')
    .put(function(req, res) {
        Data.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function(err, data) {

            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            for (prop in req.body) {
                data[prop] = req.body[prop];
            }

            // save the movie
            data.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err);
                res.json({ message: 'Data updated!' });
            });

        });
    })
```

```html
<form name="myForm1">
<ion-view title="Add Detail">
  <ion-header-bar align-title="center" class="bar-balanced">
    <ion-nav-bar align-title="center" class="nav-title-slide-ios7 bar-balanced">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
  </ion-header-bar>

  <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" class="padding">
    <div class="list"  >
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="customer" ng-model="movie.custname" required>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="problem" ng-model="movie.problem" required>
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <textarea ng-trim="false" rows=8 placeholder="Details" ng-model="themovie.details" required></textarea>
      </label>
        </div>
    <button class="button button-full button-balanced" clicked-disable ng-disabled="myForm1.$invalid" ng-click="updateMovie()">
      Add
    </button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
</form>
```

Appreciated if you can point out what I should fix. The problem that I get is when two client app (i.e, client app1 and client app 2) enter this Historiesadd page -> input records -> save. It will get this error. If client1 enter this Historiesadd page -> input record ->  save. And then client2 enter this Historiesadd page -> input record -> save. It will not get this error. That mean, the second client cannot enter the Histroiesadd page until the first client save the record successfully. It can avoid this error. I am not sure if it is backend node express issue or fontend Angular. Thanks

Comment: I get error when push child row record (add Histories) from two clients which enter this add Histories page at the same time. It works fine if only push child record one by one client (i.e, enter add Histories pages to push record in client 1 and then enter add Histories pages to push record). Is there some record lock handling required in angularJS?

Comment: I get error when push child row record (add Histories) from two clients which enter this add Histories page at the same time. It works fine if only push child record one by one client (i.e, enter add Histories pages to push record in client 1 app and then enter add Histories pages to push record in client 2 app). Is there some record lock handling required in angularJS?

Comment: Use a code snippet when the code is runnable on Stack Overflow, otherwise, just use code sample formatting (indent 4 spaces).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem relies here.

```
 for (prop in req.body) {
      data[prop] = req.body[prop];
  }

 // save the movie
 data.save(function(err) {
 if (err)
     res.send(err);
     res.json({ message: 'Data updated!' });
 });
```

You are attempting to resend json back to client after it has been already resend. Make sure save is already complete before return back the json. Try to put res.json outside callback

```
 // save the movie
 data.save(function(err) {
 if (err)
     res.send(err);
 });

 res.json({ message: 'Data updated!' });
```

Comment: I try your suggestion to put res.json({ message: 'Data updated!' }) outside callback. Unfortunately, the problem is still persist.

Comment: Try commenting res.json and replace  all  res.send(err) with throw err, what will it output?

Comment: I change as below

Comment: I change as below. But the error is same
 data.save(function(err) {
                if (err)
                //res.send(err);
                throw err;

            });
                //res.json({ message: 'Data updated!' });
        });
    })

Comment: It is found that if I change res.send(err) to return res.send(err). The error did not prompt but the second push data is not save to the mongo. Only first push data is save successfully.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what u're doing here. Can u explain a little bit. You want to update multiple child doc in mongodb?  I found a bug in your angularjs code.  $scope.movie = Movie.get({ id: $stateParams.id }).$promise.then(function(results) {
            // Don't use same name as promise name. Change this to other name.
            $scope.movieResults = results;
        });

Comment: Sorry to let you confused. The problem that I get is when two client app (i.e, client app1 and client app 2) enter this Historiesadd page -> input records -> save. It will get this error. If client1 enter this Historiesadd page -> input record -> save. And then client2 enter this Historiesadd page -> input record -> save. It will not get this error. That mean, the second client cannot enter the Histroiesadd page until the first client save the record successfully. It can avoid this error. Hope you can understand. Thanks

Comment: Oh, now i get it. You have multiple client that access 1 method in nodes. That's mean you have 2 or more users actively connected to nodejs server right?

Comment: As you notice, nodes is a single threaded mean that it will execute task1 until finished, if there is task2 coming, it will wait until task1 is finished until then it is execute. You should try using async library that can handle multiple callback at the same time check this link out -> [link](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Comment: I am new to angular. Is there any demo / sample code for this approach? Many thanks.

Comment: Is anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: This error will come if you try to send the response back to the client more than once i.e. calling res.send or res.json more than once for the same user session.

Comment: any one can help please?

Comment: Hey. You still hasn't got the answer yet.

Comment: I just noticed that you don't return callback anyway. Callback is an asynchronous equivalent for a function. With callback , it can process a high number of requests without waiting for any function to return results. Let me update my answer.

Comment: I guess you should read something like this in order to understand properly your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062990/does-node-js-handle-client-requests-one-by-one

Comment: Hi digit, Do you mean my controller does not handle callback?