# Node.js - general callback-queue order

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

refering to the answer + comments on this topic: [Does Node.js handle client requests one by one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062990/does-node-js-handle-client-requests-one-by-one)

I have a question about the callback queue order of I/O events.

When event-loop gets request1 (db-req) from userX followed by a request2 by userZ (db-req), is it possible that the response from request2 arrives earlier than response1 like in this picture (async tasks from req1 and req2 are always executed sequentially from the event queue but the response2 from the async task arrives faster then response1 because req1 takes more time):
[image]

Or would they execute sequentally (req1->req2) but response1 always finishes first since its the first that went into the callback queue. response2 waits its turn whether response1 takes longer time to process than response2.

Comment: No, they would not execute sequentally but rather when the asyn stuff finished

Comment: Tasks can take variable amounts of time to complete, thus sending callbacks to the callback queue in variable order. The callback queue is processed first in first out. Therefore, yes, it is possible for request two to return first, if it's async operation was quicker than request one's async operation.

Answer (score 0):

req2 could certainly finish before req1 as long as something in the request is asynchronous. If they were both totally synchronous then req1 would return first.