# Nodejs, Express and Promises - am I implementing this correctly?

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I have written an Express route where the input data is parsed through 3 different functions in order - I realised after some further testing that it was queuing requests and returning them one at a time.

I have made the functions return promises now and chained them inside the route function; all the Promise examples I've looked at are built around small functions where it is obvious how to implement error handling. My implementation seems to work now but I'm wondering if a) it was correct to use Promises here and b) whether my implementation is correct/how I can handle errors.

```js
function promiseFunction1(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      //for loop {
          //if statement {
              arr.push(etc);
           }
      }
      resolve(arr);
   });
}

function promiseFunction2(arr){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
      //if statement{
       }
      //nested{
           //loops{
           }
      }
      //process data

      resolve(data);
   });
}

app.post('/route', function(req,res){
//prep data and declare variables then:

var var1 = promiseFunction1();
var1.then(function(result){
    var2 = result;
    var nextVal = promiseFunction2(var2);
        nextVal.then(function(data){
            res.send(data);
        });
    });
}
```

I am just a bit hesitant to call this 'correct' given every Promise example I look for is either waiting for an API call or a function to resolve and not just some time consuming loops (so am I right to implement promises in these conditions?), and also every example I've seen handles errors inside the Promise function but that is generally specific to functions called from inside the promise itself - I take it in my instance I should handle errors against the Promise functions where they're called inside the route function instead?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of your `promiseFunction`s look to do anything asynchronous, so they should not require the construction of a Promise. Instead, you can simply call those functions, and have them return the desired value *synchronously*:

```
function myFn1() {
  //for loop {
  //if statement {
  // arr.push(etc);
  // }
  return arr;
}

function myFn2(arr){
  //if statement{
    //nested{
      //loops{
      //}
    //}
  //}
  //process data
  return data;
}
```

Note that, since there is nothing asynchronous here, you need to `return` instead of `resolve` at the end.

Then, in `.post`, you can call those functions which return non-Promise values, and use the value immediately, without having to call `then` on it first:

```
app.post('/route', function(req,res){
  const result = myFn1();
  const nextVal = promiseFunction2(var2);
  res.send(nextVal);
});
```

If there is a possibility of those functions throwing errors, since they're synchronous, surround them in a `try` / `catch`:

```
app.post('/route', function(req,res){
  try {
    const result = myFn1();
    const nextVal = myFn2(result );
    res.send(nextVal);
  } catch(e) {
    // handle errors
  }
});
```

Comment: That’s how I had it written initially however it was blocking requests until the res.send() of the one before it was called. If I don’t need to implement promises I’m guessing I just have a variable scoping issue..

Comment: If there is actual *blocking* going on, it sounds like the calculations being done in `myFn1` and `myFn2` are just too expensive. It shouldn't have anything to do with Promises. Promisifying something that isn't asynchronous to begin with won't help.

Comment: Yeah it's fully blocking - one request will not begin until the instant the one before it resolves. I did find an improperly declared variable though which I think is the culprit, I'll test and post back. In any case, you have clarified promise usage for me - the error handling in the examples I saw was against async operations (hence why I was confused about how to implement it). Thankyou!

Comment: I think this is my issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062990/does-node-js-handle-client-requests-one-by-one
Am I right in assuming that given my routes mainly consist of data manipulation across an array that is already stored in memory that there is really no way around the requests being processed one by one in order of submission? There is no I/O involved, and nothing that can be run asynchronously as far as I can tell.

Comment: That's right, your data processing just takes too much CPU time. It's like running an `for` loop 10,000,000 times - turning it into a Promise doesn't help, the interpreter needs to completely finish one expensive synchronous call before moving on to the next.