# Problem with parallel request when migrating to kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

We run an app that's built with Node.js in a microservice-based architecture. Now I've migrated the whole stuff to bare-metal Kubespray Kubernetes with Nginx as an ingress controller, but I've got an issue understanding a phenomenon when analyzing the request from my chrome browser in the Inspect Network Tab, the app before did generate a parallel request to the app but the one in k8s is taking one-continued request that is a little longer than the first architecture requests (we use Nginx in the previous architecture for reverse proxy).

Old architecture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/37R3Y.png

K8s architecture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksKDx.png

Any Help, please ?

Comment: I would expect this behavior if the node server can only handle a single request at a time. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: for the part of node server handling of requests here's an issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062990/does-node-js-handle-client-requests-one-by-one, but I don't think that's the problem cause I use the same version with the same conf in both architectures inside an already built docker image.

Comment: Then its maybe the ingress controller that "serializes" the calls. What are you using?

Comment: Are you using http2?

Comment: Yes I'm using http2